# Character falling through floor unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had this working just fine until I decided I wanted to change how I organized the colliders just a few minutes ago to avoid having multiple colliders on the same object.

I have a "Player" object with a boxCollider2d with isTrigger=false and an empty child called "triggers" which itself has 2 children, each with a single boxCollider2d and both with isTrigger=true. These triggers are used for detecting when the player is grounded or next to a wall but are not supposed to affect the physics.

I also have a "floor" object which has a sprite and an empty child called "colliders" which has a single child called "ground" with a single boxCollider2d (isTrigger=false) and the layer of the object set to "Ground".

My understanding is that since my player has a non-trigger collider (and rigidbody) and the floor has a non-trigger collider (at least its child does), that the character shouldn't pass through the floor. Also, it's starting from a height above the ground so it's not an intersection problem.

My best guess is that somehow the child colliders of the player being triggers are turning the main collider into a trigger or that for some reason the floor collider being in a child is screwing with it, but I don't know enough about how these colliders work to really know.

Comment: Its unlikely to be related to the triggers.

Comment: what was the colliders when it worked?

Answer (score 0):

The child trigger colliders should not cause it to mess up like that.

Check Project Settings -> Physics 2D -> Layer Collision Matrix. Are your objects not able to collide?